# DynamoDB: how to receive notification?

Tags: .net, amazon-dynamodb

I have N DynamoDB .NET client applications work with the same table.
How can one application receive notification when other application added/updated/deleted items in a table?

Comment: Google DynamoDB streams

Comment: Thanx @ErmiyaEskandary ! Do you know where can I find any .NET samples ?

Comment: ok, I work with this link but there is no stream examples . ;-)